# Calling setter once on function static variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, static

I'm using a function static variable that I want to initialize once by calling a setter:

```
void foo() {
    static Obj obj;
    obj.setName("name"); // this should be called once
    // use obj
}
```

I don't want the setter to be called multiple times, also due to multi threading issues and I can't add a constructor to Obj since I don't own the code. So is this reasonable and thread safe:

```
void foo() {
    static Obj obj = []() {
        Obj o;
        o.setName("name");
        return o;
    }();
    // use obj
}
```

Comment: Why a setter of all things? Why can't it have a proper c'tor?

Comment: Why dont you use constructor: `static Obj obj("name");`

Comment: I forgot to mention, that's not my code, I don't own Obj. I'll edit the question

Comment: maybe add second class which will be used to initialize Obj, like `static ObjSet objset(obj, "name");` ObjSet will initialize obj. I suppose this should be safe

Comment: But if `obj` might be used by some other thread before its name is set then you might have a problem

Comment: @marcinj, isn't this covered by new thread safety rules for function static variables in C++11?

Comment: yes it should be thread safe, your solution also looks fine in my opinion.

Comment: I would not use a lambda there:  I would use a named function, and its name would be something like `MakeInitializedObj()`.  That way, you keep the init code from cluttering up your `foo()` function.  (Note: That seems to be exactly the opposite of what @StoryTeller would do.  We could have a lively discussion about that if we both were members of the same dev team.)

Comment: It will work fine. Alternative static objects which I think are clearer than the lambda function: (1) derive from Obj to add a constructor that can call setname, (2) define a container class for Obj that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's thread safe. Quoting n3337 - [[stmt.dcl]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/stmt.dcl#4), emphasis mine:

> ...such a variable is initialized the first time control passes
>   through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized
>   upon the completion of its initialization. If the initialization exits
>   by throwing an exception, the initialization is not complete, so it
>   will be tried again the next time control enters the declaration. **If
>   control enters the declaration concurrently while the variable is
>   being initialized, the concurrent execution shall wait for completion
>   of the initialization.**

You perform copy initialization from a lambda's return value, but it's immaterial. The paragraph above doesn't constrain the initialization of `obj` to be value or direct initialization. All forms of initialization are applicable.

And as a side note, if you must contend with such poorly written types, I'd argue your solution is very idiomatic. It doesn't artificially introduce a new named function to perform the initialization. Instead it keeps initialization code localized. That is a good thing in my book.